# Passing arguments to React component using ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, destructuring

I am trying to create a sortable list with the react.js library "react-sortable-hoc" (https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc).

In "SortableList" I map a function on each element of array which (should) create a "SortableElement" with the arguments *key*, *index* and *value*. This is how "SortableElement" is defined: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/src/SortableElement/index.js

```
SortableItem = SortableElement(({value,key}) =>
    <Row>
      <this.DragHandle/>
      <ControlLabel>Question</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
        componentClass="textarea"
        placeholder="Enter question"
        onChange={()=> {
          console.log(key);       //why undefined??
          console.log(value);
        }
        }
      />
    </Row>);

SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((value, index) =>
          <this.SortableItem key={`item-${index}`}
                             index={index}
                             value={value}/>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Unfortunately, *key* and *index* are always undefined, and I just don't understand why. If you are interested in the full code, please visit https://github.com/rcffc/react-dnd-test/blob/master/src/SortableComponent.js

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source for `react-sortable-hoc`, you'll see that when passing props in the render, `index` is omitted. Also, `key` isn't passed in props. If you change your destructuring to log props in `SortableItem`, you'll see an object containing just the value ('Question 1', 'Question 2', etc). If you need to access the index or key, pass them as different props.

e.g.

```
SortableItem = SortableElement(({value,yourIndex}) =>
    <Row>
      <this.DragHandle/>
      <ControlLabel>Question</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
        componentClass="textarea"
        placeholder="Enter question"
        onChange={()=> {
          console.log(yourIndex);
          console.log(value);
        }
        }
      />
    </Row>
);

SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((value, index) =>
          <this.SortableItem key={`item-${index}`}
                             index={index}
                             value={value}
                             yourIndex={index} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: Right, I need to access key in the SortableElement. What do you mean by saying "pass them as different props"?

Comment: Notice the `yourIndex` prop I pass in the example. Rename it as appropriate.